# Creating *.rpm file based on *.deb file

Tags: linux, installation, eclipse-rcp, debian, packaging

I develop primarily in Windows/Mac environment with limited knowledge on Linux. To package my eclipse RCP project, I created 2 deb files (one 64bit and another 32bit) in Ubuntu 64bit in the virtual box. I tested these 2 deb files in 64bit and 32bit ubuntu and they worked.

Now, I want to create the RPM files for these 2 deb files. Do I use [alien](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/) to convert these deb files to rpm files? Is that a preferred way? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alien is terribly hacky when it works, and useless when it doesn't. It's better to learn [how to build a RPM](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/BuildingPackagesGuide) properly.